# Error while updating user group in django?

Tags: python, django, permissions, usergroups

Here I am trying to add/update group name and user permissions and i tried like this.

For add it is working fine but while updating with function `edit_user_group` i got problem.
The problem is

> Exception Type:   IntegrityError Exception Value:  (1062, "Duplicate
>   entry 'Developer' for key 'name'")

I think this is because of OneToOne relation. How can I update user group here ?

views.py

```
@permission_required('organization.add_user_group', raise_exception=True)
def add_user_groups(request):
    form = AddUserGroupForm()
    user_permissions = Permission.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddUserGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            permissions = request.POST.getlist('user_permissions')
            new_group = Group.objects.create(name=group_name)
            new_group.permissions.set(permissions)
            messages.success(request, 'New group added.')
            return redirect('organization:view_user_groups')
    return render(request, 'organization/add_user_groups.html', {'user_permissions': user_permissions, 'form': form})

@permission_required('organization.edit_user_group', raise_exception=True)
def edit_user_group(request, pk):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
    user_permissions = Permission.objects.all()
    form = AddUserGroupForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddUserGroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            permissions = request.POST.getlist('user_permissions')
            group = Group.objects.update(name=name)
            group.permissions.set(permissions)
            messages.success(request, '{} group Updated.'.format(group.name))
            return redirect('organization:detail_user_group',group.pk)

    return render(request,'organization/edit_user_group.html',{'group':group,'form':form,'user_permissions':user_permissions})
```

forms.py

```
class AddUserGroupForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

template for edit group

```
               <form action="{% url 'organization:edit_user_group' group.pk %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                      <label> Group Name : </label>
                       <input type="text" value="{{group.name}}" name="name">
                      <b class="text-danger">
                       {{ form.name.errors|striptags }}
                      </b>

                    <label>Permissions ({{user_permissions|length}}):</label>
                    {% for permission in user_permissions %}              
                        <input name="user_permissions" type="checkbox" id="permission-{{permission.id}}"
                          value="{{permission.id}}"
                        {% if permission in group.permissions.all %} checked {% endif %}>
                        <label for="permission-{{permission.id}}"> {{permission.name}}</label>
                    {% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**
As @ Shashank  suggested 
While trying get it returned model object but says

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Group' object has no attribute 'update' 

group = Group.objects.get(pk=pk).update(name=name)
```

And while using filter it returned int instead of instance so it throws

```
Exception Value:    
'int' object has no attribute 'permissions'

group = Group.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(name=name)
```

Comment: I guess you need to filter the model object first and then update it's value, like
`MyModel.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(val=val)`

Comment: `group.permissions.set(permissions)` this line is giving you error because update method might be returning `int`, can you try to split things like `group =  MyModel.objects.filter(pk=pk)` so that you can get that filtered object and then `group.update` and then change permission. Make sure that group object is not a list (like after filter do `group = group[0]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line that you wrote is updating every `Group` - `group = Group.objects.update(name=name)` and when it tries to it doesnt work because of the unique constraint on name.

How about replacing with `group.name = name`, `group.save()`

Answer (score 2):

The integrity exception is basically telling you that somewhere in your code you are trying to set the *name* for different group objects into 'Developer' which is prohibited (due to UNIQUE constraint).

In your function `def edit_user_group(request, pk)`, instead of `Group.objects.update`, you should do `Group.objects.get(name=name)`

i.e. From

```py
group = Group.objects.update(name=name)
```

To

```py
group = Group.objects.get(name=name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your intent is not totally clear - do you want to (also) change the group name or just change the permissions (and using `update()` instead of `get()``was just a typo) ?

In the first case, you want:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name=name)
group.name = name
group.save()
group.permissions.set(permissions)
```

**But** since there's a unique constraint on `Group.name`, you have to validate this too before saving.

In the second case, you of course just need

```
group = Group.objects.get(name=name)
group.permissions.set(permissions)
```

This being said, using modelforms would save you a lot of time and pain...